# Bulma react weird behavior

Tags: reactjs, bulma

I am trying to follow the examples at: 
https://couds.github.io/react-bulma-components/?selectedKind=Dropdown&selectedStory=Default&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Fstories%2Fstories-panel

There the dropdown expands on click and the mouse pointer changes to the link symbol on the items in the dropdown. There is also hover coloring of the items. When I try on my own the dropdown expands on hover, the mouse pointer does not show the link symbol on the items and there is no coloring on hovering. I wrote it like:

```
    <Dropdown value={this.state.visualising} onChange={this.changeVisualising} {...this.props}>
              <Dropdown.Item value="foo">foo</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item value="bar">bar</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item value="buzz">buzz</Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown>
```

Could I be missing some dependency that it is not complaining about and just silently failing? Why do I get completely different behavior?

Oh also I don't get the arrow pointing downwards either...

---

Edit: I have made an small example which can be found at: https://github.com/jonalv/bulma-react-example

Comment: oki, hoverable apparantly doesn't mean that the items change color when hovering on the but that the dropdown happens on hover. So at least that explains that. Still can't get the icon nor the hover on the items behaviour though...

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';

import Dropdown from '.';

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: 'active',
  };
  onChange = selected => {
    this.setState({ selected });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.onChange} color="info" {...this.props}>
        <Dropdown.Item value="item">Dropdown item</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item value="other">Other Dropdown item</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item value="active">Active Dropdown item</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item value="other 2">Other Dropdown item</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Divider />
        <Dropdown.Item value="divider">With divider</Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown>
    );
  }
}

storiesOf('Dropdown', module)
  .add('Default', () => (
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Item value="item">Dropdown item</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item value="other">Other Dropdown item</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item value="active">Active Dropdown item</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item value="other 2">Other Dropdown item</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Divider />
      <Dropdown.Item value="divider">With divider</Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown>
  ))
  .add('Hoverable', () => (
    <Dropdown hoverable>
      <Dropdown.Item value="item">Dropdown item</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item value="other">Other Dropdown item</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item value="active">Active Dropdown item</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item value="other 2">Other Dropdown item</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Divider />
      <Dropdown.Item value="divider">With divider</Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown>
  ))
  .add('Controlled component', () => <Wrapper />)
  .add('Controlled component Hoverable', () => <Wrapper hoverable color="dark" />);
```

Please compare along with this!

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting state active for your Dropdown bulma-react component. In their github repo there is this function with state active

```
  state = {
    selected: 'active',
  }
  onChange = (selected) => {
    this.setState({ selected });
  }
```

And top Dropdown has `onChange={this.onChange}`

Comment: I would say that I do: https://github.com/jonalv/bulma-react-example/blob/master/src/App.js#L18
and https://github.com/jonalv/bulma-react-example/blob/d245feb1ad6ba1cec4d8392297b49f2a384f3a83/src/App.js#L31